# Resizing childrens of JFXListVIew - JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, size, jfoenix

I'm having an issue resizing the children inside of a ListView, the width property just doesn't want to resize.

My structure goes like.

```
-SplitPane 
  -AnchorPane
   -ListView 
    -AnchorPane <-- I'm having the problem here, width property just doesn't resize
      (children of the AnchorPane) 
      -Vbox, Hbox... (All with the setHgrow(..., Priority.ALWAYS)
```

Here's the code simplify:

```
        private JFXListView<Node> listView;
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(); <-Here's the problem
        HBox mainHBox = new HBox();
        mainHBox.setMinHeight(73);
        mainHBox.setMinWidth(297);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(mainHBox);
        listView.getItems().add(anchorPane);
```

[I added a purple color to the AnchorPane to see the actual size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swAfi.png)

So, the initial sizes of the AnchorPane are 297,73 but is a children of a splitpane, so I looking the resize those values(Width) with the new value of the splitpane.

I already try the adding the property of `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` in the AnchorPane. I also try binding the size of the anchorpane with the size of the splitpane without success

Comment: `JFXListView` class is part of [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/) and so is not part of core JavaFX.

Comment: public class JFXListView<T> extends ListView<T>, so....